# Axios fetch data as an Array() not an Object

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

I need some help. When I try to make a get request by id from the server with Axios, I receive the object inside an Array and when I try to display the properties I'm getting undefined....

```
export const getBlog = async (id: string) => {
    const { data } = await axiosInstance.get<IBlog>(`/blogs/${id}`);
    console.log(data);
    return data;
};
```

[image]

Comment: try as `data[0].propname` ...

Comment: can you share where you are trying to display the property which throws undefined

Comment: The route /blog/:id was wrong defined...So when I have made a request to /blog/${id} I have got all the blogs items into an array... I did not realize because I had just a single item in the collection.